# SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed -- Android error

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I have seen some other questions about this, but none of the answers really seemed to work for my code. I'm getting a 'SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed' error when I try to insert into my DB. Here is the code for the insert operation. db.insert returns a -1 right now, which leads to the "failed to insert" message.

Here is the the relevant Content Provider code:

```
public static final String PROVIDER_NAME = "com.oliverapps.provider.DB";

public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://"+ PROVIDER_NAME + "/tasks");

public static final String _ID = "_id";
public static final String CATEGORY = "category";
public static final String STORE = "store";
public static final String DESCRIPTION = "description";
public static final String DISTANCE = "distance";
public static final String CHECKED = "checked";

private static final int KEY_CATEGORY = 1;
private static final int KEY_STORE = 2;
private static final int KEY_DESCRIPTION = 3;
private static final int KEY_DISTANCE = 4;
private static final int KEY_CHECKED = 5;

private static final UriMatcher uriMatcher;
static{
    uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "category", KEY_CATEGORY);
    uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "category/store", KEY_STORE);
    uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "category/store/description", KEY_DESCRIPTION);
    uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "category/store/description/distance", KEY_DISTANCE);
    uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "checked", KEY_CHECKED);
}


//---for database use---
private SQLiteDatabase tasksDB;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "tasks";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "tasks" +
        "";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE +
    " (" + _ID +  " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
    CATEGORY + " text not null, " + STORE + " text not null, " + DESCRIPTION + " text, " +
    DISTANCE + " text not null, " + CHECKED + " text not null);";

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        Log.w("Content provider database", "Upgrading database from version " +
                oldVersion + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}


@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values){
    //---add a new task---
    long rowID = tasksDB.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, "", values);

    //---if added successfully---
    if(rowID > 0){
        Uri _uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI, rowID);
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(_uri, null);
        return _uri;
    }
    throw new SQLException("Failed to insert row into " + uri);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreate(){
    Context context = getContext();
    DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    tasksDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return (tasksDB == null)? false:true;
}
```

Here is the relevant code from the Android Manifest:

```
    <provider android:name="DBProvider"
        android:authorities="com.oliverapps.provider.DB" />
```

And here is the relevant code that calls the insert method above:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(DBProvider.CATEGORY, category);
                values.put(DBProvider.STORE, store);
                values.put(DBProvider.DESCRIPTION, description);
                values.put(DBProvider.DISTANCE, distance);

                Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(DBProvider.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Any clue why this isn't working? This is mostly code from an Android book I have, modified to my own database.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The typical errors are following:

- You're trying to insert `null` values for columns which are constraint to be not `null` (so maybe missed to set values, maybe even because of wrong column constant definition).
- You're inserting same value for a column which is declared unique (typical primary key column)
- You set values of wrong type for insert (e.g. column is `integer` but you set a `string`)

I think you forgot to set `CHECKED` so it's `null` and violates the `not null` constraint.

Comment: The DATABASE_CREATE code is in the Content Provider code above... as for the other notes...I am literally entering my own data, so I know there are no null values, I have checked the values entered while debugging to make sure the correct strings are being input. I believe I have saved all my columns as strings, so no string to integer or double conversion needs to be done. And the only unique value here should be the _id, which I do not input myself (I think the DB will automatically put one in for me...if im wrong on this PLEASE let me know)....any other thoughts?

Comment: I'm Sorry, I somehow missed those constants... I updated my answer.

Comment: you are absolutely right, missed adding the checked since it was not input. Thank you!

Comment: If you define an int and you entered 10 million, java is going to take it as a long not an int. This scenario may cause SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: